# SQL Parameter throwing exception

Tags: vb.net, oledbconnection, sqlparameter

I have a function in vb.net module that is meant to get the number of records in an access database.

```
Function CalculateRecords(ByVal column As String, ByVal table As String)
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Using connect As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        connect.Open()
        Using com As New OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(@column) FROM @table", connect)
            com.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@column", column))
            com.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@table", table))
            count = com.ExecuteScalar
        End Using
    End Using
    Return count
End Function
```

Every time it's run an `Incomplete sql clause` exception is thrown. Through trial and error I found that the problem lies with the `@table` parameter. If rewritten this way:

```
Function CalculateRecords(ByVal column As String, ByVal table As String)
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Using connect As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        connect.Open()
        Using com As New OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(@column) FROM " & table, connect)
            com.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@column", column))
            count = com.ExecuteScalar
        End Using
    End Using
    Return count
End Function
```

The function works just fine. Where am I going wrong with my parameters?

Comment: Parameters won't work on table names.  You need to use the real  names there.  Parameters are used to supply the value for a field in the query.

Comment: Easy enough a fix, thanks for the speedy response!

Comment: If using `SqlServer` you could use parameter's as table names and do a replace on them with dynamic sql...